# Get Checked Value for Both RadioButtons and CheckBoxes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have an event that can be triggered by a change of the checked value of some checkboxes and some radiobuttons. I want to get the Checked value of the control that triggered the event. I know that if it is a checkbox I can do something like `bool checkedValue = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;`
(and same for radiobuttons). but what if I don't know the type of the control? Is there a class for both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to use an interface, but according to your comment on Felice Pollano's answer you don't want to.

I would then suggest to look for the type at runtime:

```
bool checked;
if (sender is CheckBox)
 checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
if (sender is RadioButton)
 checked = ((RadioButton)sender).Checked;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is the "ugly" solution, but this is the shortest, and I didn't know about the "is", thanks!

Comment: It's not a beauty contest winner, but if you limit it to CheckBox and RadioButton it's not THAT ugly either. I'm glad it worked out for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running .NET 4 you might want to try this ugly trick:

```
private void checkBox1_Click(dynamic sender, EventArgs e) {
    bool isChecked = sender.Checked;
    textBox1.Text = isChecked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
}
```

not very type safe, but fun!

Answer (score 1):

They both derive from `ButtonBase` but `ButtonBase` does not implement `IsChecked`. As a suggestion create two subclass of `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`, declare an Interface, ie `IHasCheck`, implement it properly in your derived classes, and try to cast at this interface in the event handler:

```
 public interface ICheckable
    {
        bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
    class RadioButtonExtended : RadioButton,ICheckable
    {

    }
    class CheckBoxExtended : CheckBox, ICheckable
    { 
    }
```

Comment: So I'll have to change the classes of all my radiobuttons and checkboxes?

Comment: With my strategy, yes, if you don't want, follow the strategy suggeted by Sascha. I think mine is more clean in term of object orientation.

Comment: @Sascha Thanks: +1 to yours because a good hack too. I added the code to clarify Cokegod

Answer (score 1):

You may build a small function taking a control parameter. Then try to cast first to Check box, if not null use the Checked result. If null, try the same with radio button. If that's null too, throw an InvalidParameterException or something appropriate. Else return the value you saved.

```
bool GetChecked(object ctrl) {
    bool result = false;
    CheckBox cb = ctrl as CheckBox;
    if ( null == cb ) {
        RadioButton rb = ctrl as RadioButton;
        if ( null == rb ) {
             throw new Exception ( "ctrl is of the wrong type " );
        }
        result = rb.Checked;
    } else {
        result = cb.Checked;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not tried to compile, just to provide the idea. Second idea: do a bit reflection, look if there's a property named Checked and get the value. Rough, untested Code:

```
bool GetChecked(object ctrl) {
    bool result = false;
    Type reflectedResult = ctrl.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = reflectedResult.GetProperties();
    List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> properties = ctrl.GetProperties ().Where ( itm => itm.Name == "Checked" ).ToList ();
    if ( properties.Count == 1 )
    {
        bool result = (bool)properties[0].GetValue ( ctrl, null );
    } else {
        throw new Exception ( "ctrl is of the wrong type " );            
    }     
    return result;
}
```

Though I don't like the code of both...

Comment: You can use itm => itm.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && itm.Name == "Checked" instead of itm => itm.Name == "Checked" to be sure it's a boolean property.